# static array definition error c++

Tags: c++

Error while declaring static array inside a function with function parameter

```
 int fun(int x)
 {
      int a[x];  //No Error
      static int b[x];   //Error "storage size of x is not constant
      int *f = new int[x+1];  //NO ERROR--NEW OPERATOR USED TO DEFINE THE ARRAY
 }
```

What should be changed in 2nd line inorder to declare the array "b" without any error.

Comment: What do you think of the compiler suggestion ? In c++ you should use `std::vector<>` in such cases

Comment: The root problem here is that `const int b[x]` is allocating memory at *compile time* so `x` cannot be a variable (it's value is not known at compile time), whereas `int *f = new int[x+1]` allocates memory at *run time* (because of the `new`), so `x` can be a variable. As @quantdev says, use a different type, or use dynamic memory allocation, such as `int *b = new int[x];`.

Comment: It's also useless if it were to work. You'd be creating a const array at runtime and be unable to initialise it with usefull data.

Comment: Note that `int a[x];` is not valid C++ either. It's a [C feature](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) that certain compilers, most notably GCC, accept in C++ as a language extension. Do use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**There's no way to declare a 'const' array with non-constant storage size.**

Instead use a vector.

```
int fun(int x)
{ 
  const int b[x];   //Error "storage size of x is not constant
  vector<int> b(x); //ok
}
```

Also int a[x] isn't correct either. C99 does support non constant array size, but generally, x needs to be a constant.

Comment: `vector<int>` is not a replacement for `const int []` because he wants to store `const int`s.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Then do `vector<const int>` and provide initialization data.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Feel free to make those changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you cannot define a array of const something without initializing it and if it is of a dynamic size there is no way to initialize it!